# Register service worker after hard refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, offlineapps

Whenever the web application with service worker is reloaded after hard refresh (`Ctrl + F5` for Chrome, for example), the service worker is unable to register afterwards.

According to the documentation at [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#navigator-service-worker-controller)

> Note: navigator.serviceWorker.controller returns null if the request
>   is a force refresh (shift+refresh). The ServiceWorker objects returned
>   from this attribute getter that represent the same service worker are
>   the same objects.

So, the question is: is it really impossible to register service worker right after the **hard refresh** is performed? I am checking the existence of the service worker with the `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`. Please see the attached GIF which shows interaction with the https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/ page

[image]

Comment: Try right clicking on the browser refresh icon. Select Empty cache and hard reload. Note that option is only there when you have the dev tools open.

Comment: @Mathias Same behaviour was observed

Comment: This is what I exactly faced and I solved it by reloading the page when navigator.serviceWorker.controller goes null after hard reloading.

Answer (score 5):

It seems pretty hard to prevent the hard refresh, but you can detect that a worker should be used but isn't currently. Then you can reload using it.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
  // There's an active SW, but no controller for this tab.
  if (reg.active && !navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    // Perform a soft reload to load everything from the SW and get
    // a consistent set of resources.
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Workaround solution for making service workers work even after hard reload is by unregistering and registering the service worker scripts through the code snippet below.

```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL).then(function (sw) {
          if (sw) {
            sw.unregister().then(() => {
              navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        const url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/service-worker.js';
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(url).then(function (sw) {
          if (sw) {
            sw.unregister().then(() => {
              navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by @Durim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816077/231788) was on the right track... here for reference (and indubitably I’ll find it again the *next* time I need to do this) is a full solution combining every technique, every check, such that when the promise returns you can be *sure* (barring outside interference) that the service worker is available, hard reload or not:

```js
export default async function registerServiceWorker(tryOnce = false) {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) throw new Error('serviceWorker not supported');

    const url = (new URL(`/http/script/_sw.js?hash=${swhash}`, location)).toString();
    console.info('Registering worker');
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(url, {
        scope: '/',
    });

    const registeredWorker = registration.active || registration.waiting || registration.installing;
    console.info('Registered worker:', registeredWorker);
    if (registeredWorker?.scriptURL != url) {
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Old URL:', registeredWorker?.scriptURL || 'none', 'updating to:', url);
        await registration.update();
        console.info('Updated worker');
    }

    console.info('Waiting for ready worker');
    let serviceReg = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    console.info('Ready registration:', serviceReg);

    if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        console.info('Worker isn’t controlling, re-register');
        try {
            const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/');
            console.info('Unregistering worker');
            await reg.unregister();
            console.info('Successfully unregistered, trying registration again');
            return registerServiceWorker();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`ServiceWorker failed to re-register after hard-refresh, reloading the page!`, err);
            return location.reload();
        }
    }

    let serviceWorker = serviceReg.active || serviceReg.waiting || serviceReg.installing;
    if (!serviceWorker) {
        console.info('No worker on registration, getting registration again');
        serviceReg = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/');
        serviceWorker = serviceReg.active || serviceReg.waiting || serviceReg.installing;
    }

    if (!serviceWorker) {
        console.info('No worker on registration, waiting 50ms');
        await sleep(50); // adjustable or skippable, have a play around
    }

    serviceWorker = serviceReg.active || serviceReg.waiting || serviceReg.installing;
    if (!serviceWorker) throw new Error('after waiting on .ready, still no worker');

    if (serviceWorker.state == 'redundant') {
        console.info('Worker is redundant, trying again');
        return registerServiceWorker();
    }

    if (serviceWorker.state != 'activated') {
        console.info('Worker IS controlling, but not active yet, waiting on event. state=', serviceWorker.state);
        try {
            // timeout is adjustable, but you do want one in case the statechange
            // doesn't fire / with the wrong state because it gets queued,
            // see ServiceWorker.onstatechange MDN docs.
            await timeout(100, new Promise((resolve) => {
                serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', (e) => {
                    if (e.target.state == 'activated') resolve();
                });
            }));
        } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
                if (serviceWorker.state != 'activated') {
                    if (tryOnce) {
                        console.info('Worker is still not active. state=', serviceWorker.state);
                        throw new Error('failed to activate service worker');
                    } else {
                        console.info('Worker is still not active, retrying once');
                        return registerServiceWorker(true);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // should be unreachable
                throw err;
            }
        }
    }

    console.info('Worker is controlling and active, we’re good folks!');
    return serviceWorker;
}

export class TimeoutError extends Error { }

/**
 * Run promise but reject after some timeout.
 *
 * @template T
 * @param {number} ms Milliseconds until timing out
 * @param {Promise<T>} promise Promise to run until timeout (note that it will keep running after timeout)
 * @returns {Promise<T, Error>}
 */
export function timeout(ms, promise) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new TimeoutError);
        }, ms);

        promise.then((result) => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve(result);
        }, (error) => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            reject(error);
        });
    })
}
```

All the `console.info` statements are there for your debugging pleasure and should probably be removed in production.

Obviously you'll want to change the `/http/script/_sw.js?hash=${swhash}` part (the URL of the service worker). Note a further technique here where the URL contains the hash (provided externally) of the service worker file for updates; this might not be appropriate for your use-case, make it your own.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the browser reload code in your service-worker ready function. For my case, I use [register-service-worker](https://github.com/yyx990803/register-service-worker) on GitHub, just add browser reload code like this.

```js
register('/service-worker.js', {
    registrationOptions: { scope: './' },
    ready (registration) {
      console.log('Service worker is active.')
      // This will reload the page if the controller value is null after hard-reload
      // So service worker will be registered correctly
      if (window.navigator.serviceWorker.controller === null) {
        window.location.reload()
      }
    },
    registered (registration) {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached (registration) {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound (registration) {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated (registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a very complicated story, the long road here is:

> This is actually a spec of Service Worker. And only present in recent
>   change of Chrome. For the earlier version of Chrome , Service Worker
>   has no any issue surviving a "force refresh".

Meaning, that only in the recent change of Chrome, the problem persisted. In earlier version it did not persist, what hints about a problem with chrome. **This quote was up to the year of 2016** - *All versions after this will suffer the same effect*, only earlier versions will not present the issue.

there are developers that are suggesting that `force refresh` or `hard refresh` ***should always clear out all kind of caches***. Which is matched with the purpose of its existent and its spec - *however the match I personally believe it's debatable*.

---

**the solution:**

You will be able to do it using js plugins which detect the key hit of Ctrl or Shift... then prevent the "force refresh" to happen.

*This is so far the best an easiest solution to handle the issue.*

Comment: Such attempts at interception is fundamentally incomplete (you *can’t* intercept all force refreshes), and user-hostile to boot (the user expressed intent and you’re thwarting it). Please don’t even try doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem here is not about hard refresh specifically, rather,
"How can we guarantee that the service worker after being 'activated' is also controlling the page?"
This guarantee obviously goes against the spec, but there are use cases (like mine) which may require that guarantee.

There are 3 key moments in the lifecycle of the page/service-worker combination that we need to focus on:

1. Page load

   a. Is there a service worker available already?

   b. If available, does it also control the page?
2. Service Worker activation

   Service worker just got activated,
   so it definitely does not control the pages.

   Do I wait for a navigation, when the browser will automatically give the service worker control; or do I just claim all clients by myself before that happens,from the service worker itself?
3. Page controlling service worker

   If the service worker controls the page we have achieved our objective.

   `console.log` this in development to check when this happens and ensure it happens before any dependencies that rely on it. (use a promise or observable or whatever method you prefer)

---

The way I have chosen is:

1. After the service worker activates, claim all clients to make sure it controls the page, even on the first load.
2. On page load, if a worker is activated and but does not control the page, make it control the page without a refresh.

---

For this to work, the first thing I needed was a way for 2-way communication between worker and client, because I would use that, to tell the service worker to claim the clients

First, we need a helper function to enable 2-way communation between the client and service worker.
The following function `messageSW`, copied from the 'workbox' library, helps with that.

This is on the client-side

```
function messageSW(sw, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
        messageChannel.port1.onmessage = (event) => {
            resolve(event.data);
        };
        sw.postMessage(data, [messageChannel.port2]);
    });
}
```

Next, again, inside the browser client

```js
async claimClients(sw: ServiceWorker) {
  await messageSW(sw, {type: 'CLAIM_CLIENTS'});
}
```

Then inside the service worker

```
self.addEventListener('message', async event => {
 switch(event.data?.type) {
  case 'CLAIM_CLIENTS': {
   await self.clients.claim();
   event.ports[0].postMessage(true);
  } break;
  // other case statements for other messages
 }
});
```

---

Now, claim the client once the service worker activates. This also works if it's already activated (ex: on hard refresh):

On the client:

```js
function async claimWhenSWReady() {
  const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();

  if (!reg) {
    // no registration. first load ever
    // wait for worker to become active, then claim client
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(ready => claimClients(ready.active!))
  }
  else {
    // registration exists, and is active
    // but you could add a sanity check at this point to verify that the 
    // state of the service worker is in fact 'activated'

    if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      // service worker is active but does not control the page
      // let's change that
      await claimClients(activeSW);
    }
  }
}
```

---

You'll probably want to use these functions as early as possible. I use angular and workbox, so I have tried to convert my code to be as library-agnostic as I could, and give you the primary working parts. I will leave the exact implementation to you as an exercise since your stack and dependencies will likely be different than mine.

---

If you are using workbox, then you must ensure that, if a worker already exists, it controls the page BEFORE you call register. Otherwise, `workbox.getSW()` will never resolve when you use it in your web app.